# Strange behavior of buffo.Scanner reading file line-by-line

Tags: go

i use bufio.Scanner for reading a file line-by-line into the variable wordlist ([][]byte)

This is the code (tested with go 1.1 / 1.3).

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fle, err := os.Open("words.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer fle.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(fle)

    n := 1000
    dCnt := 5
    var wordlist [][]byte

    for scanner.Scan() {
        if len(wordlist) == n {
            break
        }
        word := scanner.Bytes()
        for ii := 0; ii < len(wordlist); ii++ {
            if string(word) == string(wordlist[ii]) {
                log.Println(ii, string(word), string(wordlist[ii]))
                log.Println(len(wordlist), "double")

                dCnt--
                if dCnt == 0 {
                    for i, v := range wordlist {
                        fmt.Println(i, string(v))
                    }
                    log.Fatal("double")
                }
            }
        }
        wordlist = append(wordlist, word)
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

words.txt is a file of 5040 lines of permutations of the sequenz "abcdefg":

```
line 1 .. 
abcdefg
abcdegf
abcdfeg
abcdfge
..
line 510 ..
afcdbge
afcdebg
afcdegb
afcdgbe
afcdgeb
.. line 5040
```

generated by this small python script:

```
from itertools import permutations as perm
c = "abcdefg"
p = perm(c, len(c))
with file('words.txt','wb') as outFle:
    for i in xrange(5040):
        n = ''.join(p.next())
        print >> outFle, n
```

The problem is, that after running the above go program the wordlist contains the following:

index string(wordlist[])

```
0 afcdebg      <-- this is line 513 of words.txt
1 afcdegb
2 afcdgbe
3 afcdgeb
...
510 bdefcag
511 bdefcga
512 afcdebg    <-- this is the begin of a repition of line 513 .. 1024 in words.ttx
513 afcdegb
514 afcdgbe
```

Instead wordlist should contain the first 1000 lines of words.txt

Any Ideas ?

The answer was given by Daniel Darabos (see below)

changing

word := scanner.Bytes()

to

word := scanner.Text() ' did the job.

(Thanks for your help!)

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include a description of what the code is supposed to do? Without telling us what you want it to do, you cannot complain that it does not do that :).

Comment: @Daniel As stated in the last line above, the go program should have filled up the wordlist with the words contained in words.txt (line separated). And you got the right answer.

Comment: Whats strange anyhow is, that i'v got the repetition of the 512 lines. Furthermore, i can't see what scanner.Bytes() is good for, if it can't be stored- maybe making it a private method would be more appropriate? Or is it good for something i can't see?

Comment: I guess it has a buffer for 512 lines and rotates around. So you put references to the same arrays multiple times in `wordlist`. `Scanner.Bytes` is good for accessing the data :). If you want to keep a copy of it, it's your responsibility to copy it out. I've added a bit more on this to the answer. Let me know if it still does not make sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation of [`Scanner.Bytes`](https://godoc.org/bufio#Scanner.Bytes) says:

> The underlying array may point to data that will be overwritten by a subsequent call to Scan.

So if you save the returned slice, you can expect to see its contents change. This wreaks havoc in your application. Better to not save the returned slice!

A nice solution is to build a string from the bytes:

```
word := string(scanner.Bytes())
```

Then you can work with strings everywhere and the code becomes more pleasant.

### What is going on?

Why does `Scanner.Bytes` hate me? The answer is also in the documentation:

> It does no allocation.

This makes the Scanner nicely efficient. From what you see, I guess it allocates buffers for 512 lines in the constructor and then rotates over them.

This is not a problem in applications where you do not need to keep references to the lines. (For example a `grep`-like program only looks at each line once.) Often you parse the line and store a reference to that. But if you want to store the raw byte data, you are responsible for copying it out from the `Scanner`.

This may be a hassle, but while you can implement the convenient behavior on top of the inconvenient one, it would be impossible to implement the efficient behavior on top of the inefficient one.

---

Also a simpler script for generating the input:

```
import itertools
for p in itertools.permutations('abcdefg'):
  print ''.join(p)
```

Comment: string converting the scanner-buffer worked. I need byte slices in the end so i will have to convert them again.

Comment: word:=scanner.Text() was doing the job. "perm" in the py script was itertools.permutation as you suggested.

Comment: That's enlighting. I've seen this is in the docs. Might be little more highlighted by a warning though. Maybe, i was the first one having this problem.

Comment: I agree, the documentation could explicitly say not to hold references to the slice returned by `Scanner.Bytes`. You could raise this on [golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts).